# Creating a smart data structure in Java

Tags: java, class, tree, hashtable, abstract-data-type

So I'm trying to create a smart data structure based off AVL tree and Hash Table.

I'm making sure I need to check first which implementation the data type will have depending on the size the list given to it.

For example, if I have a list n of size 1000, it'll be implemented using a Hash table. For anything more than 1000, using an AVL tree.

Code for this:

```
public class SmartULS<K,V> {

protected TreeMap<K,V> tree = new TreeMap<>();
protected AbstractHashMap<K,V> hashMap = new AbstractHashMap<K,V>();

public void setSmartThresholdULS(size){
    int threshold = 1000;
    if (size >= threshold) {
         map = new AbtractMap<K,V>();
    }
    else
         map = new TreeMap<K,V>();

    }
}
```

Now after this, I should be writing the standard methods such as

get(SmartULS, Key), add(SmartULS, Key, Value), remove(SmartULS,Key), nextKey(Key), previousKey(Key), etc.

I'm really lost as to how to start this? I've thought about creating these methods like this(written in pseudo):

```
    Algorithm add(SmartULS, Key, Value):
i<- 0
If SmartULS instanceof AbstractHashMap then
For i to SmartULS.size do
        If Key equals to SmartULS[i] then
            SmartULS.get(Key).setValue(Value)
        Else
            SmartULS.add(Key, Value)
Else if SmartULS instanceof TreeMap then
    Entry newAdd equals new MapEntry(Key, Value)
    Position<Entry> p = treeSearch(root( ), Key)
```

Comment: Please read [ask]

Comment: @EngineerDollery Instead of posting that, you could help the guy out.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the correct track, this is how I understood your question and implemented it:

```
public class SmartULS<K, V> {

    Map<K,V> map;

    public static final int THRESHOLD = 1000;

    public SmartULS(int size) {
        if(size < THRESHOLD) {
            map = new HashMap();
        } else {
            map = new TreeMap();
        }
    }

    public V get(K key) {
        return map.get(key);
    }

    public V put(K key, V value) {
        return map.put(key, value);
    }

    public V remove(K key) {
        return map.remove(key);
    }
}
```

Based on the initial size given, the constructor decides if to initialize a hash table or a tree. I also added a the get, put and remove functions and used the Map's interface functions.

I didn't understand what the nextKey and previousKey functions are suppose to do or return, so couldn't help there.

A way of using the class would be as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    SmartULS<String, String> smartULS = new SmartULS(952);

    smartULS.put("firstKey",  "firstValue");
    smartULS.put("secondKey",  "secondsValue");

    String value = smartULS.get("firstKey");

    smartULS.remove("secondKey");

}
```

Hope this helps:)